# Why doesn't UPDATE query work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote a stored procedure to update record. It mentions salary detail for each BPS in each YEAR and same BPS cannot exist 2 times in same year i.e.

```
BPS     Year
01      2014
02      2015
02      2015  (wrong)
```

This stored procedure doesn't work.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Setup.SalaryChart WHERE SalaryChartID = @SalaryChartID)
BEGIN
      IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Setup.SalaryChart 
                WHERE BPS = @BPS AND Year_ID = @Year_ID 
                  AND SalaryChartID != @SalaryChartID )
      BEGIN
            RAISERROR('Record already exists for selected BPS',16,1) 
            RETURN  
      END
      ELSE
        IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Setup.SalaryChart 
                  WHERE BPS = @BPS AND Year_ID = @Year_ID 
                    AND SalaryChartID = @SalaryChartID)
        BEGIN
            --UPDATE OF THE RECORD
            UPDATE Setup.SalaryChart
            SET BPS = @BPS,
                Year_ID = @Year_ID,
                FromDate = @FromDate,
                InitialSalary = @InitialSalary,
                Increment = @Increment,
                MaxSalary = @MaxSalary,
                IsActive = @IsActive,
                SystemUser_ID = @SystemUser_ID
            WHERE 
                SalaryChartID = @SalaryChartID
        END
  END
```

Update:

For Example:

I have record

```
BPS   Year   Salary     Bonus
01    2015    $100       $1
```

now I i update this record to change only bonus figure then it will fail on EXISTS check.

Comment: @lad2025: sir, glad you answered but I can't find anyway, I have spent a lot of time and can't find out

Comment: complete you table including salary chart id, provide the step by step expected results given a certain values

Comment: To help you, I ned to see the data you have in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way:

The easiest way is to add `UNIQUE` constraint on your table.

```
ALTER TABLE Setup.SalaryChart
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_SalaryChart UNIQUE(BPS, [Year]);  -- probably also SalaryChartID
```

Custom checking could be slower and error-prone.

---

As for your SP you should use `IF cond ELSE`. I do not see point of `IF cond ELSE cond ...`

Comment: ok sir but how to throw or raise error in that case ? from SP  ?

Comment: sir the code you wrote won't work. I tried it before because it will fail if in case of updation is don't change BPS and YEAR; will throw error for the record I am updating because it also exists

Comment: @Quoran `UNIQUE` is still valid. As for your stored procedure: 1) Schema and sample data 2) http://sqlfiddle.com demo 3) Desired result

Comment: Wait I am updating the question

Comment: @Quoran By schema and sample data I meant: SQL Scripts (CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO/CREATE PROCDEURE...).